# Need help creating DataGridView that looks for selected cell value

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm fairly new to programming and am having a bit of trouble. I need to create a loop that will count all the rows in my datagrid and then do an if statement to check a cell value. I want to leave auto generate columns on.

Here's the code I have so far

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        for (int x = 0; x < dataGridView2.Rows.Count -1; x++)
        {
            int m = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView2.SelectedRows[x].Cells[2].Value);

            if (m == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Code 1");

            }

            if (m ==2 )
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Code 2");
            }
        }

    }
```

The first if statment that checks if cell 2 is 1 works fine. However, when I add another row it will give the "Code 2" messagebox but crash with a (Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection).

Given that I have auto column generation on wouldn't my for statement keep the value of the selected row within the range?

Any help would be awesome! thanks guys :)

Comment: I think you misunderstand what `SelectedRows` is. It is a collection of the "selected rows". Unless every row is selected you will get an index error when you try to loop over the entire grid.

Comment: Conversely, there can be no rows selected.  it would be awesome of you read [ask] and took the [tour].  (and unless you poked data into the rows/columns it would be faster/better to iterate the DataSource)

Comment: Ah! Thanks Crowcoder. That's exactly what the issue was. I was able to figure it out from there

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out thanks to Crowcoder. I was misunderstanding what the .SelectedRows did.

Here is my fixed code

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        for (int x = 0; x < dataGridView2.Rows.Count -1; x++)
        {
            int m = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[2].Value);
            if (dataGridView2.Rows[x].Selected)
            {
                if (m == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Code 1");

                }

                if (m == 2)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Code 2");
                }

            }

        }

    }
```